# RegEx match pattern within a line only if line begins with a specific criteria

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, sentence

How do I match a pattern within a line, only if line begins with a specific criteria?

For example, say we'd like to match a `6-digit` number on lines with begin only with `Banana`

```
Banana lmasfh asfjhas jhona uh3 a y u3u3 303303 ajksdfkas 3jk5hk

Banana lmasfh asfjhas jhona uh3 a y u3u3 202202 ajksdfkas 3jk5hk

Apple lmasfh asfjhas jhona uh3 a y u3u3 101101 ajksdfkas 3jk5hk
```

From above, the result should be `303303` and `202202` only.

I tried looking into positive lookbehind but they're of fixed width and couldn't proceed. Something like: `(?<=^Banana)\d{6}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close. There is just "stuff" (which is easily handled with `.*` in regex) in between. Then add a match group and there you go.

```
(?<=^Banana).*(\d{6})
```

Will put both `303303` and `202202` into match group one. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/k87i7x/1

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not familiar with match groups and that's where I was stuck I guess. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could leave out the lookbehind and match it instead, and add word boundaries `\b` to prevent partial matches:

```
^Banana\b.*\b(\d{6})\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xm8Nds/1)